# Controling servos with a PCA9865

Tags: power, servo

I have a basic setup controlling a servo using a [PCA9865](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCA9685.pdf).

Given some servos under full load, can they draw 1 A? I am probably going to exceed the current limit of the device. How would you control 12 servos pulling 1 A safely?

There are also some high-power servos that can run at higher voltages, like 7.4 V. Given it's a robotics project, I want as much power as I can get.

We are talking hobby servos like the ones found in RC cars, they are controlled by PWM signal. The board is marketed as a servo control board although I know its original use was to control LED.

Comment: The PCA9865 is intended as a LED controller, where each LED output can be set to either On, Off or PWM (Pulse Width Modulated), and it is not immediately obvious how the PCA9865 is connected to allow the servos to be controlled. Can you [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/702718/edit) the question to include (a) A schematic of how the servos are connected (b) A link to the datasheet for the servos.

Comment: We are talking hobby servos like the ones fpund in rc cars, they are controlled by PWM signal. The board is marketed as a servo control board although I know its original use was to control LED.

Comment: PCA9865 is a PWM controller. It outputs digital PWM signal to control the servo. The servo power does not come through the PCA9865 so it is not related in any way how to power them or does not limit how much servos can draw.

Comment: Since each servo can potentially draw 1A, powering all 12 servos simultaneously would require a power supply capable of delivering at least 12A. If the PCA9865 board cannot handle the total current required for all servos, you can use external drivers or power distribution boards to distribute the current safely.  By the way, you can also make a 6DOF Bluetooth controllable semi-autonomous robot with an ESP32 board and a PCA9685 https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/Scion_V1_Semi_Autonomous_Bluetooth_Controllable_Robot_With_ESP32_and_PCA9685_S_5584df83.html